# Boot in different OS with different button

Tags: multi-boot, bootloader

I now have a dual-boot system on my Sony Vaio laptop.

I have this "assist" button next to my power button, it would boot up in an different environment than Windows 10. I now have Linux and Remix OS on it so it doesn't work anymore.

Is it possible in one way or another to immediately go to the other OS when I press the button?
It now just boots it normally, I'd like to make use of it.

Comment: I don't think so. My best idea would be to make the boot menu so that (as you have 3 OSes) your default one is the second and then you could get two any other with two keystrokes - up or down and Enter :) - just set the default timeout to be long enough for your needs.

Comment: I have that already, but thanks! Guess I'll have to do it the boring way :P

Comment: Boring way working way :) A not so boring way would be if yo buy a programmable keyboard and program two keys for the above mentioned keyboard combo ;)